# Can basis for free module over ring have more elements than the ring has

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I'm currently studying modules and rings theory.

Now, my question is can there be a free module with $n$ elements in it basis over a ring $R$ with $m<n$ elements?
I know that every free generated module with $n$ elements is isomorphic to $R^{n}$.
but I don't see any contradiction with the ring having less than $n$ elements in it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: "Every finitely generated module with $n$ elements is isomorphic to $R^n$". This is not true at all. You are talking specifically about free modules here. Most finitely generated modules are not free.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will update the post. thank you

Comment: Ok, so answering your question, there are no restrictions on the size of $R$. If $R$ is any ring, $R^n$ is a free module with a basis of $n$ elements. The ring $R$ itself can have less than $n$ elements.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you